# Return value from a function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, return

Why does this return None?

```
def pow(num,num1):
    if num1 < 1:
        print("in if num ",num, "num", num1)
        return num
    else:
        num = num * num
        print("in else num ",num, "num", num1)
        num1 = num1 - 1
        pow(num,num1)

f= pow(2,4)
print(f)
```

Comment: your else condition doesn't return anything

Comment: Last line has to be `return pow(num,num1)`

Comment: as @SebastienD and @tobias said, your else statement does not return anything so at the end of execution code is returning `None`, you want to avoid this then use `return pow(num,num1)` in your else statement.

Comment: I get that the missing return was the issue. But how does the value of the variable inside the function get updated after each recursive call?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the missing `return` statement, note that your logic is also wrong. You are repeatedly squaring the number in each step, not mulitplying it with the original number. E.g., for `pow(n, 3)` your code would calculate ((n²)²)² instead of n*(n*(n)). Also, in order to be a proper `pow` function (assuming that is what you wanted to write), the `num < 1` case should return `1`, not `num`, so that `pow(n, 3)` returns n*(n*(n*1)) and not n*(n*(n*n)).

```
def pow(num, num1):
    if num1 < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num * pow(num, num1 - 1)
```

This way, you pass the *original* value of `num` to the recursive call, and not the squared value.

(Having said that, for any practical application you should of course use the builtin `pow` function or the `**` operator, just in case you did not know these.)

---

> But why does the value not get returned from the if block? The value is getting updated n each of the recursive calls, if you execute and see the output.

You calculate the value and store it in the *local* variable `num`, but that does not change the value of what was previously assigned to that name (numbers are immutable!). Thus you need `return` to get it out of the function. See this example:

```
def test(num):
    num = num * 2
    print("inside", num)
    return num

n = 5
r = test(n)
print("outside", n)
print("returned", r)
```

Comment: Adding the return works fine. Thank!
But why does the value not get returned from the if block? The value is getting updated n each of the recursive calls, if you execute and see the output.

Comment: @YaswanthViswanath **because you aren't returning anything** so by default, it returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

Because the final `pow(num,num1)` calls itself without getting the return value from the call and, more importantly, *doesn't return* the return value that it's not getting :-)

You'll probably find it works better if you return something other then the default `None`:

```
return pow(num,num1)
```

Once you do that, you'll find the return value (final line below) is what you desire:

```
in else num  4 num 4
in else num  16 num 3
in else num  256 num 2
in else num  65536 num 1
in if num  65536 num 0
65536
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning the value in the recursive call:

```
pow(num,num1)
```

try:

```
def pow(num,num1):
if num1 < 1:
    print("in if num ",num, "num", num1)
    return num
else:
    num = num * num
    print("in else num ",num, "num", num1)
    num1 = num1 - 1
    return pow(num,num1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine as per your input.

output:

```
    in else num  4 num 4
    in else num  16 num 3
    in else num  256 num 2
    in else num  65536 num 1
    in if num  65536 num 0
```